# Deleting a file with TransferManager Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using TransferManager to upload and overwrite existing files on S3. For instance:

```
Upload uploadExample = transferManager.upload(bucketName, key, file);
```

I could theoretically upload a blank file to delete, but I do not want to do this. Is there another way to delete (Uploading a null file perhaps?)? I don't see anything like it in the API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TransferManager is for handling transfers i.e. uploads and downloads. Therefore you don't need the TransferManager to delete a file. You can do this directly via the [AmazonS3 client class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html) (which can be used to construct a TransferManager). For example:

```
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    try {
        s3Client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName));
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        ...
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        ...
    }
```

For more information see [Deleting an Object using the AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingJava.html)